# how to convert between a container of a derived type to a container of a base type

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, type-conversion

I have a C++03 application with a class that holds a single instance of a type where I am trying to convert between a holder of a derived type to a holder of a base type. For example:

```
class B { public: virtual ~B() { }; };

class A : public B { };

template< typename T >
class Container
{
public:
    explicit Container( T* obj ) : obj_( obj ) { };
    Container( const Container< T >& ref ) : obj_( ref.obj_ ) { };

    template< typename U > operator Container< U >() { 
        return Container< U >( obj_ );
    };

private:
    T* obj_;
};
```

This works fine:

```
int main()
{
    Container< A > a_ref( new A() );
    Container< B > b_ref = a_ref;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the error `invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Container<B>&’ from expression of type ‘Container<A>’`:

```
void Foo( Container< B >& cb ) { }

int main()
{
    Container< A > a_ref( new A() );
    Foo( a_ref );
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the error `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Container<B>&’ from a temporary of type ‘Container<B>’`L

```
int main()
{
    Container< A > a_ref( new A() );
    Foo( static_cast< Container< B > >( a_ref ) );
    return 0;
}
```

How can I pass a `Container< A >` type to a function that expects a `Container< B >` type? Do I need to make a copy of the object first?

Comment: Yes, you have to make a copy. Even if A is derived from B, one container is not derived from the other. They are totally separate types.

Comment: `a_ref` is not a... ref(erence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Container<A>` and `Container<B>`are totally different class.

You can have something like `container_cast<T>(U)`  that converts a `Container<A>` to `Container<B>`

container_cast will construct another `Container<T>` by taking the `obj_` `Container<U>` and casting that `obj_` to `T*`

Comment: though in some specific cases (where you need read-only access) a cast may be safe. This depends also on the container type: `vectors` are naturally off the game, but `list`, `map` and etc. (i.e. those that allocate a separate node per element). Plus this depends on the implementation details. In particular if container's node first declares its private variables, and lastly the object of your type - the type cast **is** safe.

Comment: Yes as the question mentions only one `T* obj_` thats why I followed this way in my answer. however I've never practiced the same yet, and also I've never been in such situation too. but this way it should work.and I don't think this is a bad design.

Comment: As far as I understand it, `Foo( container_cast< B >( a_ref ) );` will give me an error about taking the reference of the temporary object created by the container_cast. Unless you know a way to implement `Container<T>& container_cast( Container<U>& )`.

Comment: You can design `container_cast` to return another `Container` that copies internal `obj_` into it and casts as well.

Comment: Exactly. The copy would be a temporary. The Foo() function would be taking the reference of a temporary. Unless I misunderstand.

Comment: No If you copy then don't return a reference rather return that object itself. and write a simple copy constructor.

Comment: @PaulH: I meant something like this http://ideone.com/byt3C. why are you intentionally passing a temporary to a reference argument ?

Comment: @NeelBasu: OKay, thanks. I see what you're getting at now. Is this better than just doing `Container<B> b_tmp( a_ref ); Foo( b_tmp );`

Comment: Why would `Foo` take a reference first ? .and as you are just copying a pointer,not making a deep copy. So copying is not much overhead at all. its just like copying an integer.

Comment: as I've never practiced the same by myself I cannot share you my experiences in doing the same. But if you still need to use references  there should not be a lot of tricks in doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Add another constructor:

```
template <typename U>
Container(Container<U> const & ref,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, U>::value, int>::type = 0)
: obj_(ref.obj_)
{ }
```

I added the `enable_if` part to make sure that this new constructor template only participates in overload resolution when the type `U` is actually derived from `T`.

Comment: I don't think you need the `enable_if`, normal SFINAE should take care of it.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: Think about `std::is_constructible<Container<A>, Container<B>>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB - Thanks, but `std::enable_if` is C++11. This is a C++03 project.

Comment: @PaulH: `enable_if` is the most trivial one-liner which you can easily write yourself.

Comment: @KerrekSB: My implementation leaves something to be desired. Could you take a look and let me know if you spot my mistake? 
http://ideone.com/HnROC

Comment: @PaulH: Say `Foo(Container<B> const & cb)`. You can't bind a temporary to a non-const lvalue reference.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the container, use an iterator pair, which is nicely convertible to base class. It solves the problem, and cleans up the code in one go.

---

**EDIT**: after more info was given, I change my answer to this:

Use `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I don't think container in this case is referring to anything resembling an STL container (I misread this at first) - but purely a holder for a single instance of another class - this iterators are not appropriate.

Comment: a holder for a single instance of a class is `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr` or `std/boost::shared_ptr`. It's not a container.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson - you're correct. I'll modify the question to make that clearer.

Comment: @rubenvb -Yes, it is from a 3rd party library and is similar in concept to a `boost::shared_ptr`